# Loopback ACL “Authorization Required” using mySql Connector

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I want users in specific roles to be able to write data to the endpoint, and for some reason the user I have set up (which is in one of those roles) cannot write. I get a following error : Below is my code .

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    let today = new Date();

    let admin = {
        name: 'admin',
        description: 'admin users',
        created: today.toJSON(),
        modified: today.toJSON()
    };

    let internal = {
        name: 'internal',
        description: 'Internal users',
        created: today.toJSON(),
        modified: today.toJSON()
    };

    let external = {
        name: 'external',
        description: 'external users',
        created: today.toJSON(),
        modified: today.toJSON()
    };

    let bot = {
        name: 'bot',
        description: 'robots',
        created: today.toJSON(),
        modified: today.toJSON()
    };

    let model = app.models.user;

    model.create([
        {username: 'bot', email: 'example@example.com', password: 'test123'},
        {username: 'admin', email: 'example2@example.com', password: 'test123'},
        {username: 'iAdmin', email: 'example3@example.com', password: 'test123'},
        {username: 'eUser', email: 'example4@example.com', password: 'test123'},
    ], function(err, users) {

        if (err) throw err;

           app.models.Role.create(bot, function (err, botRole) {

            if (err) throw err


                botRole.principals.create({principalType: app.models.RoleMapping.USER, principalID: users[0].id}, function(err, principal) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });


        });

        app.models.Role.create(admin, function (err, adminRole) {
            if (err) throw err;

            adminRole.principals.create({principalType: app.models.RoleMapping.USER, PrincipalID: users[1].id}, function(err, principal) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        });

       app.models.Role.create(admin, function (err, internalRole) {
            if (err) throw err;

            internalRole.principals.create({principalType: app.models.RoleMapping.USER, PrincipalID: users[2].id}, function(err, principal) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        });

        app.models.Role.create(external, function (err, externalRole) {
            if (err) throw err;

            externalRole.principals.create({principalType: app.models.RoleMapping.USER, PrincipalID: users[3].id}, function(err, principal) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        });
    });
};
```

model-config:

```
"User": {
    "dataSource": "mySqldb",
    "public": false
  },
  "user": {
    "dataSource": "mySqldb",
    "public": true
  },
  "AccessToken": {
    "dataSource": "mySqldb",
    "public": false
  },
  "ACL": {
    "dataSource": "mySqldb",
    "public": false
  },
  "RoleMapping": {
    "dataSource": "mySqldb",
    "public": false,
    "options": {
      "strictObjectIDCoercion": true
    }
  },
  "Role": {
    "dataSource": "mySqldb",
    "public": false
  }
```

ACLS:

```
"acls": [
    {
        "accessType": "*",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "$everyone",
        "permission": "DENY"
    },
    {
        "accessType": "READ",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "$authenticated",
        "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
    {
        "accessType": "WRITE",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "admin",
        "permission": "ALLOW"
    },
     {
        "accessType": "DELETE",
        "principalType": "ROLE",
        "principalId": "admin",
        "permission": "ALLOW"
    }
  ],
```

Error :
ValidationError: The `user` instance is not valid. Details: `secret_key` can't be blank (value: undefined); `logged_in_with` can't be blank (value: undefined); `username` is invalid (value: "bot"); `email` is invalid (value: "example@example.com").

Comment: what's the error you got??

Comment: @Subburaj in the after save operational hook , i want to write the logic so that the data i am receiving from the ctx i.e ctx.instance.email , i.e i have to insert into USER model , how i can do this ?